# Parsing JSON style text using sscanf()

Tags: c++

```
["STRING", FLOAT, FLOAT, FLOAT],
```

I need to parse three values from this string - a STRING and three FLOATS.

sscanf() returns zero, probably I got the format specifiers wrong.

```
sscanf(current_line.c_str(), "[\"%s[^\"]\",%f,%f,%f],", 
            &temp_node.id, 
            &temp_node.pos.x, 
            &temp_node.pos.y, 
            &temp_node.pos.z))
```

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: `%s[` can never succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the manual page on sscanf(3). The %s format does not match using a regular expression, it just scans non-whitespace characters. Even if it worked as you assumed, your regular expression would not be able to handle all JSON strings correctly (which might not be a problem if your input data format is sufficiently restricted, but would be unclean nonetheless).

Use a proper JSON parser. It's not really complicated. I used cJSON for a moderately complex case, you should be able to integrate it within a few hours.

Comment: `%[...]` (not `%s[ ]`) is a valid scanf directive. It's not a regex.

Comment: You're right. With %[^"] it would work with simple strings without escaped quotes or other special cases.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your immediate problem, use this format specifier:

```
"[\"%[^\"]s\",%f,%f,%f],"
```

The right syntax for parsing a *set* is `%[...]s` instead of `%s[...]`.

That being said, `sscanf()` is **not the right tool** for parsing JSON. Even the "fixed" code would fail to parse strings that contain escaped quotes, for instance.

Use a proper [JSON parser library](https://www.google.de/search?q=json%20c%2B%2B%20parser).